# Знание каких технологий и/или разделов Java необходимо для трудоустройства на позицию intern/junior

Tags: java

Решил сменить работу, в связи с чем возник вопрос:"А что нужно знать кроме основ циклов, массивов и строк? "

Comment: Backend и приклад(работа с БД, GUI приложения)